# How to change the order of facet.var from alphabetic in iNext function?

Tags: facet-wrap

I am trying to make a graph with multiple facets in iNext. Facets are months. Since the default is the alphabetic order, to make the panels of facet, it puts August, July, June, May. But I want the reverse order. I tried to make site (which is the month in my case) as a factor. But it did not work.

Anybody has an idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: I want to add that iNext is a fuction related to ggplot.

Comment: Is there any way to fix the order of facet wrap in the facet_wrap ( )? Like specifying levels in the function?

Answer (score 0):

I've also wanted to know how the designers wanted us to do that. My workaround was to build it up from more basic parts... below you can see how I reordered by descending elevation in the ant dataset:

```
# faceting in iNEXT
library(iNEXT)
data(ant)
adat<-iNEXT(ant, datatype = "incidence_freq")

# if you look in Anne Chao's github, you can see the source code for ggiNEXT
# it generates a df with fortify.iNEXT, which is what ggiNEXT plots

plotdf<-fortify.iNEXT(adat, type=1)

#manually relevel the factor
plotdf$site<-factor(plotdf$site, levels=c("h2000m", "h1500m","h1070m",  "h500m", "h50m"))  

#then just use your own clever ggplot ideas to make the plot you want
p<-(plotdf %>%  ggplot(aes(x,y, colour=order)) 
    + geom_point(size=1)
    + geom_line(lwd=0.5)
    + theme(legend.position = "none")
    + facet_wrap(~site)
    + theme_classic()
)

print(p)
```

https://github.com/AnneChao/iNEXT/blob/master/R/ggiNEXT.R